# hexdigest generating different values in linux and windows for same file

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, digest, md5sum

I am using Digest::MD5 module and in that hexdigest returning different value for windows and linux.

please help me in solving the issue.

```
use Digest::MD5;
my $ctx=Digest::MD5->new();
open RD, "input.txt";
$ctx->addfile(*RD);
close RD;
print $ctx->hexdigest;
```

input.txt file has below content:

```
hello
```

output: windows

```
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

output: Linux

```
af5597c29467a96523a70787c319f4db
```

Thanks,

Saravanan

Comment: How do you know those two `input.txt` are the same?

Comment: @leeduhem he could md5 them to verify!

Comment: @RobEarl Yes, he can. But he does not believe the results of md5.

Answer (score 6):

According to the comments given by the asker, the `input.txt` is generated in Windows and then is copied to Linux, then I believe the problem is caused by the difference between Windows and Linux end-of-line, in Windows end-of-line is '\r\n', in Linux '\n'.Therefore, using [`binmode()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) set the filehandler to binary mode should be able to fix this, as suggested in the examples of [`Digest::MD5`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Digest-MD5-2.53/MD5.pm).

This should fix the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Digest::MD5;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";
binmode $fh, ':raw'; # <==== NOTE this binmode()

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
$md5->addfile($fh);
print $md5->hexdigest, "\n";
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried its working after adding binmode in windows I have added binmode in windows and in linux i removed binmode now I am getting same value.

Comment: @Saravanan It is no need to remove the `binmode()` in your Windows version script.

Comment: You may prefer `binmode $file, ':raw'` to make the access mode explicit. In any case, `$file` is a poor name for anything. It could be a file name string, a file path string, or, unusually as here, a file handle. I suggest at least `$fn`, `$path`, `$fh`.

Comment: @Borodin You are right, `$file` is a bad choose for a reference of file handler. Answer updated.

Answer (score -1):

That can be because each time the hash value changes, you can refer this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5